# Differance between ip4 and ipv4 addresses, nmcli?

Tags: nmcli

When creating new interfaces with nmcli, ip address can be set with both ipv4.addresses and ip4 parameter.

Is there a differance between these?

examples

`nmcli con add ifname ens192 con-name ens192 type ethernet ipv4.addresses 192.168.0.10/24`

vs

`nmcli con add ifname ens192 con-name ens192 type ethernet ip4 192.168.0.10/24`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `nmcli` manual:

```
Table 25. IPv4 options
┌──────┬────────────────┬────────────────────────┐
│Alias │ Property       │ Note                   │
├──────┼────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│ip4   │ ipv4.addresses │ The alias is           │
│      │ ipv4.method    │ equivalent to the      │
│      │                │ +ipv4.addresses syntax │
│      │                │ and also sets          │
│      │                │ ipv4.method to manual. │
│      │                │ It can be specified    │
│      │                │ multiple times.        │
├──────┼────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│gw4   │ ipv4.gateway   │                        │
└──────┴────────────────┴────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

No, in `man nmcli`, under Table 25 "IPv4 options" you can read that `ip4` is an alias to `ipv4.addresses ipv4.method`. However it is noted that:

> The alias is equivalent to the +ipv4.addresses
>   syntax and also sets ipv4.method to manual. It
>   can be specified multiple times.

---

General hint: always check `info` or `man` pages when unsure.